# Hibernate / Oracle 'with' clause / Native SQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Is it possible to use the Oracle 'with' clause from hibernate?

I have the following basic example:

```
final String queryStr =
" with v_tbl as ( "+
" select distinct etc...";

final Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryStr);
final List results = query.list();
```

I get the following exception:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER  - line 1:2: unexpected token: with
```

I read an article which suggested switching to:

```
<prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
```

but that didn't seem to help.

Any suggestions?

fyi, I'm using Hibernate 3.6.7, Spring 3.0.6, Oracle 11g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use native sql query anytime

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryStr)
```

Comment: Yep, I just figured out that typo at the same time I saw this :)  Thanks!